# The homotopy set $[S^{n-1}\times S^n,S^n]$ (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory

The group $\pi_{2n-1}(S^n)$ acts on the homotopy set $[S^{n-1}\times S^n,S^n]$
by changing a map on the top cell of $S^{n-1}\times S^n$
and leaving it unchanged on
$$
S^{n-1}\vee S^n\subseteq S^{n-1}\times S^n.
$$
It is ``clear'' that
the Whitehead square
$$
[\iota_n,\iota_n]\in\pi_{2n-1}(S^n)
$$
fixes the homotopy class of the projection
$$
S^{n-1}\times S^n\to S^n.
$$

Where is this stated in the literature?

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid, but I don't understand your action of $\pi_{2n-1}(S^n)$.

Comment: @Dave Benson For any $q$-dimensional manifold $M$, there is a ``coaction'' $M\to M\vee S^q$: collapsing the boundary of a ball in $M$ gives $M\vee S^q$. It follows that, for any space $Y$, the group $\pi_q(Y)$ acts on the set $[M,Y]$: a map $M\to Y$ and an element of $\pi_q(Y)$ form a map $M\vee S^q\to Y$, whose composition with the coaction is a new map $M\to Y$.

Comment: I see. Thank you.